# Find $\operatorname{ind}T$ where $T=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$

Tags: linear-transformations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be a linear and continuous operator defined as $$T=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$$
Determine $\dim \ker T$ and $\dim \operatorname{coker}T$ in this two cases:

1. $T: \mathscr{C}^2([a,b]) \longrightarrow \mathscr{C}([a,b]) $
2. $T: \mathscr{C}^2(\mathbb{S}^1) \longrightarrow \mathscr{C}(\mathbb{S}^1)  $

My attempts:

1. $\ker T =\{ u \in \mathscr{C}^2([a,b]) \quad | \quad Tu=0 \iff \dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=0 \} = \{u=mx+q| m,q \in \mathbb{R}\}$, so $\dim \ker T =2$ because the space has basis $(x,1)$

$\operatorname{im}T = \mathscr{C}([a,b]) \Rightarrow \dim \operatorname{coker}T =0$, so $\operatorname{ind}T = 2-0=2$. Is it right?

2. for the $\ker$ part it's the same and for the $\operatorname{im}T$ I don't even know how to start.

Comment: In what sense is $T$ a continuous operator?

Comment: By any reasonable definition, $T$ fails to be continuous.  Note for instance that if we define
$$
f_k(x) = \frac{\cos(kx)}{k} \quad k = 1,2,3,\dots,
$$
then $f_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ while $Tf_k$ fails to converge.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the exercise says to take $T \in \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{C}^2([a,b]),\mathscr{C}([a,b]))$

Comment: How is the norm on $\mathcal C^2$ defined?

Answer (score 1):

Your steps and conclusion regarding 1 are correct.

Regarding question 2, you might have an easier time if you identify $\mathscr C^2(\Bbb S^1)$ with the functions in $\mathscr C^2([0,1])$ satisfying the constraint $f(0) = f(1)$.  Another way to think about this is that we're considering the set of all $\mathscr C^2$ functions that are **periodic** with some fixed period.

With that said, the kernel will not be the same.  Note in particular that the function $u = mx$ fails to be periodic.  As for the image: in the same way that you deduced that $T$ was onto before, you should be able to deduce that $T$ is onto now.

Comment: I think $f(x)=kx+c$ for integral values of $k$ is periodic on $\mathscr{C}^2(\mathbb{S}^1)$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool $\mathscr C^2(\Bbb S^1)$ consists of $\Bbb R$-valued functions on $\Bbb S^1$, not $\Bbb S^1$-valued functions

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I fail to see that $\ker T$ is different. Can you explain it in details?

Comment: If the derivative of a periodic function is constant, then the function itself must also have been constant